can we implement the grpc in GoLang with the existing code?
Currently,I am exploring to use grpc with Golang for microservices communication where one microservice will act as the server and other service will be the client consuming the services from the service.
Till now, after going through the grpc/Go docs what I understood is that we need to create .proto files which will define our services and messages. After compiling the .proto files we will get the generated code in Go. We need to implement the interfaces that are in generated code in our Golang codebase. So, it seems we need to first define the .proto files and after that only we can write the Go code. Is there any way in which our existing GoLang code can be converted into proto files and generated files by protoc so that any client can use it using Grpc?

In general, it makes more sense to go with an API-driven approach here: first, define the API, e.g. in protobuf. Second, generate the clients implementing it. Just imagine you want so switch to a Node.js implementation: with your approach, you'ld need the Go implementation to generate the Node.js implemention. With API-first, you just need the - more agnostic - API definition to generate any services from it you want.


Is there any way in which our existing GoLang code can be converted into proto files and generated files by protoc so that any client can use it using Grpc?

Not in a generic way. Your code is arbitrary; protobuf definitions are not, nor are any other API definitions such as OpenAPI. It is very difficult to map from arbitrary code to structured API definitions, unless you have written your code in a restricted and parseable way that enables such structure to be identified.
The reality is I suspect that it will be very difficult to extract this structure from your code if it was not written at the outset with this intent in mind. Furthermore, REST-style API specifications likely do not map to the conventions used with gRPC-style RPC APIs, particularly around supported methods (i.e. you don't have HTTP methods in gRPC calls, so it is common to encode the method into the RPC name e.g. DeleteThing, CreateThing).

If you are intent on attempting to extract structure mechanically, you need to identify:

what is the boundaries of a service (in the gRPC sense), i.e. an interrelated set of RPC methods
what are your API methods that should be bound on that service?
what is the data type for the input and output methods, which correspond to messages in the protobuf definition?
how should the gRPC services be organised, i.e. into packages?

If your code consistently follows a certain structure, you may be able to use the native Go parsing capabilities to identify this structure from your code and emit a protobuf definition. For example, you may have a correspondence as follows:

Go struct corresponds to a gRPC service, where the receiver methods on that struct are the RPC methods on the service.
Go struct for your input and output data corresponds with protobuf message types.

